# Можно ли пометить отдельные секции исполняемого образа как незагружаемые в ОЗУ

Tags: windows, visual-studio, архивация, pe

Например в случае большого SFX-архива, до нескольких гигабайт, логично загрузить только исполняемый код распаковщика, а сам архив оставить на диске. И потом спокойно его распаковывать.

Если да, то как это сделать средствами Visual Studio? Как это вообще делается в случае SFX?

Comment: Это называется "оверлей", но беглый гуглинг не показал, что студия так умеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто делают так. Создается EXE без дополнительных данных, а потом к нему дописывается "архив", при этом параметры секций не меняются. Загрузчик в память загрузит только сам EXE, оверлей не будет загружен, поскольку он не в секции.
Запущенный EXE делает, к примеру, GetModuleHandle(NULL), получает адрес своего заголовка в памяти, парсит таблицу секций и узнает файловое смещение конца последней секции. Ровно за ним - оверлей с "архивом", который он может читать как ему угодно.
Вариант номер два: после сборки в неиспользуемые поля заголовка вносится размер EXE, и запущеный процесс читает оттуда смещение до оверлея.

Comment: Как именно поменять поля заголовка? С помощью чего? Будет ли это работать в случае DLL?

Comment: HIEW или любой другой HEX-редактор прекрасно справятся. Можно написать отдельную тулзу, которая будет автоматически все это делать. С DLL, думаю, тоже прокатит.

Comment: А известно ли вам о какой-нибудь готовой утитилите специально для этого?

Comment: Нет, если бы мне была нужна - я бы написал сам.